# text to pdf with utf8 encoding (alternative to a2ps)

Tags: pdf, unicode, printing, utf-8, ascii

The programm a2ps does not support utf-8. At least my version does only
support the latin-X encodings:

```
a2ps --list=encoding
```

Version:

```
GNU a2ps 4.14
```

How can I convert a simple utf-8 text to postscript or pdf?

Comment: See also [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197624) on unix.stackexchange.com which decsribes u2ps in addition to paps.

Answer (score 13):

If what you actually want is to use `a2ps` or `enscript` (which is a similar tool), and if your single need is to use them with some UTF-8 document, you only have to convert your document to ISO-8859-1 or some supported encoding. Various tools allow this. For instance, here is a workflow for `enscript` (but you can surely do the same with `a2ps`):

```
cat document.txt | iconv -c -f utf-8 -t ISO-8859-1 | enscript -o document.ps
```

But you may lose some characters during the conversion because such encodings have a smaller range than UTF-8.

On the other hand, if UTF-8 is a requirement, you may rather have to look for some recent tool allowing to convert UTF-8 to PDF. I wrote myself a Python program called txt2pdf; you may find it [here](https://github.com/baruchel/txt2pdf). Have also a look at tools like [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), [gimli](https://github.com/walle/gimli), [rst2pdf](https://code.google.com/p/rst2pdf/) or [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/).

Comment: Using `iso-8859-1//TRANSLIT` instead of plain `iso-8859-1` may save you some `iconv: illegal input sequence at position XX` errors.

Comment: txt2pdf seems to convert all UTF-8 characters (which are not ASCII) into small black squares.

Comment: @RogerHouse Hi, I use txt2pdf on a daily basis for my own document with no trouble. Are you sure you specified a correct font?

Comment: @ThomasBaruchel I am using /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/UbuntuMono-R.ttf and the result is mostly empty square boxes.  Probably I should find another font, but I don't know which one.  When I display my text file with cat or look at it with vim or emacs (terminal version), everything is great, but I have not found out how to successfully convert it to PDF.

Comment: @ThomasBaruchel I should mention that my text document is mostly Unicode characters, not straight ASCII.

Comment: @RogerHouse I checked with this font and didn't notice any issue. Of course the tool is intended to be used with UTF8 characters and if the glyph is in the font there should be no trouble. We have to understand what is going wrong, but certainly nothing that couldn't be fixed very quickly. Could you open an issue on Github in order to discuss more conveniently than here?

Comment: @ThomasBaruchel See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900764/how-to-convert-a-unicode-utf-8-text-file-to-pdf?noredirect=1#comment92721905_52900764) for text which results in question marks.

Comment: Yes, utf-8 is a requirement. Converting to latin1 is not a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Vim](https://www.vim.org/). Open the file and execute the command `:hardcopy > output.ps` in normal mode. You can also do this directly from the shell. Executing

```
$ vim -c ":hardcopy > output.ps" -c ":quit" input.txt
```

in your shell will open Vim, generate the `output.ps`, and then close Vim.

Comment: Thanks, it is a great answer - vim is installed on many systems by default. Before reading this answer I was installing one tool after another. Sidenote: in neovim 0.9 the :hardcopy option has been removed and it is advised to use the :TOhtml option instead and afterwards convert the resulting HTML file into PDF.

Answer (score 3):

**Use paps**! For instance I use it as follow:

```
paps --font="Monospace 10" input.txt > output.ps
```

and I have no problem with utf encoding.
If you need a pdf file then

```
pdf2ps output.ps
```

Comment: Note that [v0.7+](https://github.com/dov/paps) is probably preferred.

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten acceptable results (for printing code listings) from https://github.com/arsv/u2ps

Answer (score 2):

https://gitlab.com/gnomify/u2ps is the replacement of gnome-u2ps.

Comment: Please provide essential details from link because link may get expired in future.

Answer (score 1):

If the text file is small, paps converts to text to ps, which then can be fed to ps2pdf.  The problem is ps file from paps causes ps2pdf to create a very big pdf file.  If that is ok, this is possible.  Currently, I am having a large file size pdf from paps.

Comment: I'm the author of paps. The problem of large files from ps2pdf is no longer true in version 0.7.* . Further version 0.7.* can directly write pdf files, so you don't need ps2pdf anymore. Get the latest version from the git repo.

Comment: @DovGrobgeld Just what the doctor ordered for line printer output from mainframe emulators to be sent to a contemporary printer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's a utility based on gnome libraries and named [gnome-u2ps](http://bonobo.gnome.gr.jp/~nakai/u2ps/). It has less functionality than `a2ps`, and it seems that it is not maintained anymore.

Comment: I tried this tool years ago; I don't know if its current conversion engine is better, but at that time I found the result awful. If I remember well, outlines from a TrueType font are converted but the [hinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting) is missing. While it may be suitable for printing the output, it can certainly not be an acceptable solution for creating standalone PDF documents.

Comment: It seems no longer maintained (it depends on obsolete libraries like gnomeprint)