# How to convert unusual unicode characters (UTF-8) to PDF?

Tags: pdf, unicode, utf-8, fonts

I would like to convert a text file containing Unicode characters in UTF-8 to a PDF file.  When I cat the file or look at it with vim, everything is great, but when I open the file with LibreOffice, the formatting is off. I have tried various fonts, none of which have worked.  Is there a font file somewhere on my Ubuntu 16.04 system which is used for display in a terminal window?  It seems that would be the font to tell LibreOffice to use.

I am not attached to LibreOffice.  Any app that will convert the text file into a PDF file is fine.  I have tried txt2pdf and pandoc without success.

This is what the file looks like
[image]

To be more specific about the problem, below is an example of what the above lines look like in LibreOffice using Liberation Mono font (no mono font does better):
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "the formatting is off"? Are the columns misaligned, or are the astrology symbols displayed incorrectly, or something else? You'll need to use a fixed-width (typewriter) font in LibreOffice to see the columns aligned.

Comment: One alternative to a typesetting program is a fake printer which is installed like a regular printer driver, but produces a PDF file instead of actually printing to paper. Then you can print directly from vim, I guess.

Comment: Are you really sure that the characters are rendered with the same mono font than the digits in Libreoffice? It looks rather like a fallback font for rendering characters that are not included in the mono font. Could you tell which font you are using in Vim?

Comment: @ThomasBaruchel As far as I can make out, when vim is run in a terminal window, the font is whatever font is set up in the terminal window.  The command

    "gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name"

reports that the font is 'Ubuntu Mono 13'.  (I am running Ubuntu MATE 16.04.) This seems to be ideal for my situation because when I edit the file with vim, joe (Joe's Own Editor), or emacs (terminal version) everything is displayed perfectly.  This is also the case when I display the file in a terminal with the cat command.

Continued in next comment ...

Comment: @ThomasBaruchel However, I have not been able to figure out how to tell LibreOffice to use the terminal font.  The "Ubuntu Mono" font offered by LibreOffice, as well as all the other "* Mono" fonts do not work.  I am beginning to think this is a bug in LO.  If a font is designated Mono, shouldn't all characters display with the same width?

Comment: @RogerHouse Please, could you pastebin in some way an excerpt of your text file; I will try on my own to understand the issue. If I manage to find a relevant font to be used with txt2pdf, I will tell you. You can also send it directly to me by mail (just build the mail address by taking my lastname, then add the `AT` symbol, then add GMX dot COM).

Answer (score 0):

I answered to you by mail, but here is the answer. You are using some very specific characters; the most difficult to find being in the `Miscellaneous Symbols` unicode block. For instance the [SESQUIQUADRATE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26bc/index.htm) which sould is on your second line as `⚼`.

A quick [search](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/miscellaneous_symbols/fontsupport.htm) lead me to the two following candidates (for monospace fonts):

- [Everson Mono](http://www.evertype.com/emono/)
- [GNU Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont/index.html)

As you can see, the block is partially covered by PragmataPro *which is a very good font*; however, I tried with an old version and found all your own characters, but an issue occured because the [Sun](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2609/index.htm) character (rendered as `☉`) seems to be printed twice wider than the other characters, but my version of this font is rather old and perhaps buggy.

Once you have chosen the font suiting your needs, you may be able to render your documents as PDF with various tools. I made all my experiments with [txt2pdf](https://github.com/baruchel/txt2pdf) which I use daily for many documents.